# How do I get rid of System.InvalidOperationException for entity type 'Font' in Visual Studio 2022 C# .NET application?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, desktop-application

Hello I have a problem with my C# application. It's an app for showing all the data in our company (workers, cars etc.). Here I have the workers class and I need to show data from a database. So I tried the following code as it shown on screenshot. But when I enter to this form (view) when the application is working I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: „No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Font'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:

[SCREENSHOT FROM VISUAL STUDIO 2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHyrq.png)

Why is it showing something related to Font?

Here is the whole code for this class:

```
public class Pracownicy : Form
{
    private IContainer components = null;

    private GroupBox groupBox1;

    private Label label1;

    private CheckBox checkBox1;

    private Label label3;

    private Label label2;

    private TreeView treeView1;

    private Label label4;

    private Button button1;

    private Button button2;

    private Button button3;

    private TextBox textBox1;

    private DataGridView dataGridView1;

    public object Pracownik { get; private set; }

    public Pracownicy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form pracownicy_add_view = new Pracownicy_Add();
        pracownicy_add_view.Show();
    }

    private void Pracownicy_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using Magazin context = new Magazin();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        List<Pracownik> pracownicy = new List<Pracownik>
        {
            new Pracownik
            {
                Imie_Pracownika = "Kacper",
                Nazwisko_Pracownika = "Dudxxxx",
                Stanowisko_Pracownika = "Specjalista systemów komputerowych"
            },
            new Pracownik
            {
                Imie_Pracownika = "Piotr",
                Nazwisko_Pracownika = "xxxxx",
                Stanowisko_Pracownika = "Prezes zarządu"
            },
            new Pracownik
            {
                Imie_Pracownika = "Nxxxa",
                Nazwisko_Pracownika = "xxxx",
                Stanowisko_Pracownika = "Wiceprezes zarządu"
            },
            new Pracownik
            {
                Imie_Pracownika = "xxxxxz",
                Nazwisko_Pracownika = "Rxxxxxa",
                Stanowisko_Pracownika = "Wiceprezes zarządu"
            },
            new Pracownik
            {
                Imie_Pracownika = "Ixxxxz",
                Nazwisko_Pracownika = "Mxxxxxk",
                Stanowisko_Pracownika = "Elektromonter"
            }
        };
        context.Pracownicy.AddRange((IEnumerable<Pracownicy>)pracownicy);
        context.SaveChanges();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = pracownicy;
    }

    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && components != null)
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(magazin.Pracownicy));
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.treeView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)this.dataGridView1).BeginInit();
        base.SuspendLayout();
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.treeView1);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1445, 160);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(431, 763);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Właściwości";
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 280);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(164, 41);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label4.Text = "Powiązania";
        this.treeView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 322);
        this.treeView1.Name = "treeView1";
        this.treeView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(302, 242);
        this.treeView1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 168);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 41);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label3.Text = "Adam Nowak";
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 52);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(249, 41);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Dane personalne:";
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 111);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(226, 41);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "Imię i nazwisko:";
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 227);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 45);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "Pracuje";
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("button1.Image");
        this.button1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 56);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 70);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button1.Text = "Dodaj";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(button1_Click);
        this.button2.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("button2.Image");
        this.button2.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 56);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 70);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button2.Text = "Usuń";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("button3.Image");
        this.button3.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(479, 56);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(216, 70);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button3.Text = "Edytuj";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(845, 79);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.PlaceholderText = "Wyszukaj...";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(563, 47);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 160);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 102;
        this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 49;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1396, 820);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 6;
        base.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(17f, 41f);
        base.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        base.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1888, 992);
        base.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        base.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        base.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        base.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        base.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        base.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        base.Name = "Pracownicy";
        base.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Pracownicy";
        base.Load += new System.EventHandler(Pracownicy_Load);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)this.dataGridView1).EndInit();
        base.ResumeLayout(false);
        base.PerformLayout();
    }
```

I thought that the problem is with the whole solution but on a new project there is identical problem. So I don't have a clue what is wrong with that and why is this showing an error with the 'Font' parameter.